# Dispaly Inline Creating Inconsistent widths IE 11

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a menu where all links have a background associated with it, and displayed in an inline format. I want the widths of these elements all to be the same, but I have having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this, as the width seems to be based on the text length, padding does not seem to help with this issue as the text length varies. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Example JSFiddle:[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hexobolic/a9hpa5mL/1/)

Example:
HTML

```
<div id="menuLink"><a href="#" id="menu-link-home">Fuzz</a></div>
<div id="menuLink"><a href="#" id="menu-link-home">FuzzBuzz</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#menuLink{
    background:#cccccc;
    display:inline;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Question, are you using this to create a navigation? If so it would be better using <nav />, <ul />, <li /> with the <a /> instead of the <div /> tags.

Comment: Thanks Hatora I will look into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` elements are not affected by `width` statements.

Just make them `inline-block`.

```css
.menuLink{
    background:#ff0000;
 display:inline-block;
 width:200px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu-link-home">Fuzz</a></div>
<div class="menuLink"><a href="#" class="menu-link-home">FuzzBuzz</a></div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a9hpa5mL/2/)

Note: You can't re-use IDs on the same page so I converted those to a class.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve the same thing by changing your html structure to the most adopted practice of using ul li for navigations.

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" id="menu-link-home">Fuzz</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="menu-link-home">FuzzBuzz</a></li>
</ul>
```

Same styling is still valid:

```
ul li{
     display:inline-block; 
     width: 200px; 
     background-color:red; 
     height:50px;}
```